# Date time in Python within Azure Databricks (strftime)

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I have a field called "SuppliedDate", I import it into a StringType and the values for example are `2.2020`.

I use the following example, which works just fine; albiet I'm manually setting the value:

```py
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.strptime("2.2020", "%m.%Y")
print(my_date)
```

But when I use this within my dataframe I get the error as outlined below:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("YearMonth", datetime.strptime("SuppliedDate","%m.%Y"))

Error: time data 'SuppliedDate' does not match format '%m.%Y.
```

I've checked the formats and even tried the "%-m.%Y" but this doesn't seem to be a supported method in `Azure Databricks`. What am I missing?

Comment: could you show a sample of your df['SuplliedDate']?

Comment: An example value would be 2.2020 or 4.2020. I've confirmed the field structure is defiantly StringType.

Comment: i think you are trying to convert the string "SuppliedDate" and not the column